# My Wireless USB adapter decided to be a pain

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

I've been using the Dlink DWA 125 wireless usb adapter on my desktop computer for the past 4 years and today it has decided not to work on me. It was working last night but when I tried connecting to the internet this morning it would not work and does not show me the usual list of wireless SSID's.

I've tried,

- Restoring to an earlier windows state.
- Reinstalling new drivers for the dlink
- Updating mobo (because I thought it's a mboard usb issue??)
- running registry scan and clean
- resetting the usb settings on windows.
- tried booting in linux to see if it works but nada.

Then I used a spare Tp-Link TL WN321G usb adapter I had and it connected straight away!... but for some random reason I figured I might as well give the Dlink another shot, So I plugged that back but like before it didnt work.

...Then I went back to the Tp-Link adapter and now that' isn't working? Is it something wrong with windows?

Both adapters are showing the same thing. They are recognized fine and show "this device is working properly" under device manager but I can't connect to my router with them?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your adapter _is_ four years old. You may try it on another computer with a fresh install of drivers, if that doesn't work there's a good possibility it may have died.

Comment: This doesn't answer the fact that another USB wifi now doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Although you can try to fix complex problems with twiddling this and that and thinking the problem thru, the best and quickest way to solve problems that necessarily involve lots of complexity is with divide and conquer.

Find a way to swap some part of the bad system out.  In this case either swap out the laptop or the wireless adapter.  (Also once you think you know which part is bad, re-insert it and see if the system fails again.  And then swap it again with the known good part and make sure the system works again.  This nails intermittent problems most of the time.)

The more general technique is a binary search tree.  Cut the problem in half to find out which half is bad.  Then cut the bad half in half again to find out which half of it is bad, etc.  If you think about it the binary search tree is the fastest way to search a data set.  It should also be used for searching for problems for the same reason.

A smart old troubleshooter drilled this into my head many years ago and he was right I think.  It's the fastest, and most assured way to quickly nail down what is wrong.